# Backup the database file as sql inside the zip file on QT C++

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, zip, qprocess

I want to backup my database by creating a zip file with qprocess in the QT program, in the code below it does it as a sql file. How can I make a backup inside the zip file?

```
QProcess dump(this);
QStringlist args;
QString path="C:/Users/ali/Desktop/dbfile/db.sql";
args<<"-uroot"<<"-proot"<<"denemesql";
dump.setStandardOutputFile(path);
dump.start("mysqldump.exe",args);

if(!dump.waitForStarted(1000))
{
qDebug()<<dump.errorString();
}

dump.waitForFinished(-1);
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is perform it in two steps: dump and then zip

```cpp
bool dump1() {
    QString path = "C:/Users/ali/Desktop/dbfile/db.sql";
    QString zipPath = "C:/Users/ali/Desktop/dbfile/db.zip";

    QProcess dump;
    dump.setProgram("mysqldump.exe");
    dump.setArguments({"-uroot", "-proot", "denemesql"});
    dump.setStandardOutputFile(path);
    dump.start();

    if (!dump.waitForStarted()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }
    if (!dump.waitForFinished()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }

    QProcess zip;
    zip.setProgram("C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe");
    zip.setArguments({"a", zipPath, path});
    zip.start();
    if (!zip.waitForStarted()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }
    if (!zip.waitForFinished()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }
    QFile(path).remove();
    return true;
}
```

You can avoid creating temporary file piping ouput of dump directly to 7z,but you will be limited to gzip format.

```
bool dump2() {

    QString gzipPath = "C:/Users/ali/Desktop/dbfile/db.gz";
    QString fileName = "db.sql";

    QProcess dump;
    dump.setProgram("mysqldump.exe");
    dump.setArguments({"-uroot", "-proot", "denemesql"});

    QProcess zip;
    zip.setProgram("C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe");
    zip.setArguments({"a", gzipPath, "-si" + fileName});
    dump.setStandardOutputProcess(&zip);

    dump.start();
    zip.start();

    if (!dump.waitForStarted()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }
    if (!zip.waitForStarted()) {
        qDebug() << zip.error();
        return false;
    }
    if (!dump.waitForFinished()) {
        qDebug() << dump.error();
        return false;
    }
    if (!zip.waitForFinished()) {
        qDebug() << zip.error();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The hard way is to use zlib, you can add it to your project and use

```
zipOpen
zipOpenNewFileInZip
zipWriteInFileInZip
zipCloseFileInZip
zipClose
```

functions. This requires linking library and including headers and sources from `zlib\contrib\minizip`.

Comment: Which way would be more effective?

Comment: I'd say about the same: both solve the problem in reasonable time using reasonable amount of system resources

Comment: QString gzipPath = "C:/Users/ali/Desktop/dbfile/db.gz"; I changed .zip instead of .gz. which one would be more effective? Are there a differences between them.